# Bypass string concat in PHP readfile for LFD exploit

Tags: php, file-io, exploit

I'm taking a course on software security and have been presented with the following scenario:

PHP CODE RUNNING ON SERVER:

```php
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=response.txt");
    readfile($_GET['file']."/remove/this.txt");
?>
```

I need to know if this can be exploited to get an arbitrary file on the server (other than */remove/this.txt).

I tried using null byte (%00) but it's not working (the apache server is running PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu).

I also tried to get creative with php://filter, php://input, etc and nothing. The problem here is that the last part of the instruction is the resource.

Path truncation doesn't seem to work either. For now the only thing I can do is read URL's using ?var=...

Comment: I just analyzed the implementation. If there's any NUL-byte in the string, it'll fail. Apart from that, there's no chance. The only thing where you could have had a chance is with `php://filter`; the dumb part about it is that the `/resource=` part needs to be at the end of the string... The only critical thing is that an attacker could access servers usually not exposed to the external network. (via e.g. `http://`)

Comment: @bwoebi exactly, you understood the problem perfectly, thought I'm not ready to give up yet. For example, I was playing around and found out that in Windows "\\localhost -xxx/whatevertext" yields the same result as "\\localhost"; this doesn't solve anything for us obviously, but my point is that if we look hard and get creative we just might find something.

Comment: Did you try [`expect://`](http://php.net/wrappers.expect)? Maybe it’s installed.

Comment: @Gumbo very clever, but it's giving me the following: "Warning: readfile(): Unable to find the wrapper "expect" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"

Comment: @LorenzoWills https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/32b5f8a1a3552f48d6e91c17b6d9d441c665a44d ... that commit introduced that check, but it is 5.4 (and newer) only. You say you're running php 5.3, so, the NUL-byte thing should work I'd think??

Comment: @bwoebi it was fixed in 5.3.4 and my server is running 5.3.10. [PHP 5.3.4 Release Notes](http://php.net/releases/5_3_4.php)

Comment: @LorenzoWills okay, then seems php 5.3 and 5.4 got different fixes. sorry for being wrong ;-)

Comment: On the contrary @bwoebi, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I just ran a simple test and can say there isn't a **single** character exploit for this that would chop off the last filename part. Example:

```
<pre>
<?php

for($i=0;$i<=255;$i++){
    $chr = chr($i);

    readfile("B.txt{$chr}A.txt");
}
```

Created a file called `A.txt` that is the standard file and `B.txt` that is the target file. Put something noticeable in each file so you know when it was read (I already had the files for something else and there was a different list of like 100 items in each).

There wasn't a single character exploit on my system which is RHEL6. The obvious exploit would be if the file `remove/this.txt` existed elsewhere and you could redirect to a different directory.

Comment: Yes, I did the same, even with two chars, here's the code:

Comment: Code is too long. Anyway, I think the solution, if any, will not rely on breaking the path... perhaps something like a php://filter where the last argument can be ignored

Comment: I did fine [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726247/php-security-exploit-list-content-of-remote-php-file) that covers a few options.

Comment: nice post and discussion, but no solutions there for this

Comment: Just another thing found, [this article](http://www.ush.it/2009/02/08/php-filesystem-attack-vectors/) covers a few more options. I couldn't get any of them to work, but offers a few more ideas.

Comment: yes thank you, that was one of the first I read when looking for a solution. They made a path truncation attack which doesn't work on newer versions of PHP.